# Questions about idea consoleview

Tags: intellij-idea

I created a log query plug-in using the IntelliJ IDEA consoleview component. Pressing ctrl+f on the page will open the search box of idea by default, but it cannot always be displayed at the top. When the scroll wheel scrolls down, the search box goes to the top , cannot be displayed at the top of the current display page, how to solve this problem. My IntelliJ IDEA version number is 202.6948.69, Community Edition

I created consoleview through consoleviewimpl, and used JBScrollPane as the scrolling component, and consoleview as the ViewPort of JBScrollPane

Comment: For plugin development queries it's recommended to ask them directly at [IntelliJ IDEA Open API and Plugin Development](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development).